# what does 'takes it out of you' means?

Tags: meaning

Phoebe: We went to a self-defence class today.

Rachael: Yeah, kicking a guy in the crotch all morning, really takes it out of ya!

---

In Friends, the drama, I saw these sentances but I couldn't understand what 'takes it out of you' means.

In dictanary, it means 'exhausted'.
But I don't know why there is the word 'you' in last of the sentance.

I think exhausted person should be 'me' because Rachael learned the class and it might be made her exhausted.

Why there is 'you' in the last?

Comment: It is an idiomatic way of saying *it exhausts you*. No one knows what *it* is that gets taken out, but doing hard manual work certainly *takes it out of you* - whatever *it* is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @WS2, the idiom **take it out of** refers to an activity that makes you very tired or requires a lot of effort:

> Playing tennis in this heat really **takes it out of you**.

(http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/take-out)

The *you* in Rachel's sentence is generic. It refers to people in general:

> In English grammar and in particular in casual English, *generic you*, *impersonal you* or *indefinite you* is the pronoun you in its use in referring to an **unspecified person**, as opposed to its use as the second person pronoun.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you)

Rachel means this activity would make *anyone* tired.